# Haskell: Can't figure out how to use monad transformer stack

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have a type

```
type T s r a = StateT [s] (ListT (Reader r)) a
```

I'd like to create a monadic value that yields each of the current states

```
states :: T a r a
```

But I'm feeling stupid today, and I can't figure out how to transform a value of `T a r [a]` to `T a r a`.

```
states = do
  as <- get
  -- insert magic
  return a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured a way out

```
states = do
  as <- get
  a <- lift . ListT $ return as
  return a
```

Which can be compacted down to

```
states = get >>= lift . ListT . return
```

ok, feel smarter now